# ajax call with cronjob

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cron

I have a php file(index.php) which calls another file(ajax.php), which consists of javascript and ajax calls.

index.php, `$mid` is a variable fetched from database:

```
<?php
$url = "http://localhost/parser/ajax.php?m=$mid";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_exec($ch);
```

ajax.php :

```
<?php
$mid = $_GET["mid"];

var r = {
    feedLife: 60,
    feedParams: {
      competition: '129',
      season: SEASON,
      sport: SPORT,
      match: <?php echo $mid ?>,
    }
    };

$.ajax({
    url: 'upload_json.php?m=<?php echo $mid ?>',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(a),
    processData: false,
    success: function(){

    },
    error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
        console.log( errorThrown );
    }
});
```

I want to run a cron, but as console can not parse javascript, I have no idea how to achieve automation? Any ideas? Maybe phantomJS can do a trick?

thanks in advance

Comment: do you have an idea of serverside and clientside execution and that JavaScript is executed clientside while php runs on the server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: You can mimic the AJAX request with cURL. If you don't want to go through many cURL calls, you should consider PhantomJS. You know what to do, so get started

Comment: Can you give us the end goal of the process. It looks like you are jumping through a bunch of hoops just to pass a variable to upload_json.php. Im sure there is a reason, its just not clear what that reason is.

Answer (score 0):

you can not write javascript in php file

try to use NodeJs + Cron

Comment: @s-kav try to use NodeJs + Cron

Answer (score 0):

You have error, you need close php tag after variable $mid. Example

```
<?php
$mid = $_GET["mid"];

?>
```

Comment: It was just a typo here.

Answer (score 0):

concatenate you're all javascript code in string, and wrap in tag  and use echo

```
    <?php
$mid = $_GET["mid"];

$script = "<script> var r = {
    feedLife: 60,
    feedParams: {
      competition: '129',
      season: SEASON,
      sport: SPORT,
      match: '".$mid."',
    }
    };

$.ajax({
    url: 'upload_json.php?m=".$mid."',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(a),
    processData: false,
    success: function(){

    },
    error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
        console.log( errorThrown );
    }
});</script>";

echo $script;
```